# What is a very large room in a building called?

Tags: single-word-requests

In our university there are a few very large spaces in a building. In each of these large rooms, something about 100 people work. Each room is partitioned using 1.5 metre high fiberglass walls and has many cubicles in it. What are these large rooms called? Salons, halls or just "very very large rooms"?

Comment: You mean like an [open plan](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_plan) or [office landscape](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_landscape)?

Comment: Is this a _bullpen_?

Comment: How tall are the fiberglass walls? Do they go all the way from floor to ceiling, or are they only about a meter tall?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. The room that you can have an open plan office in it. What is that room called?

Comment: Colloquially, we'd call that a *cube farm*. Not sure about proper English, though.

Comment: A hundred different names.  A local elementary school has a large room called (I kid you not) "The Multi-Porpoise Room".

Comment: Do you ask about large rooms that have cubicles only? Can it be a large room for some other purpose and without cubicles (but not enclosed)? Is it a room or an area also (or can it be both)? [I'm asking because question title is general. Also, you can include more details and you can mention the words that do not fit.]

Comment: Foyer:a large entrance to a building,originally was a term in French that referred to a large room where actors waited when they were not on stage.

Comment: @ermanen Yes. These large rooms have cubicles only. There are two of them in our building, each with 20-30 cubicles. They are connected through a hallway. From the answers provided "cube farm" seems to be the best match, but it sounds a bit informal.

Comment: Generally, rooms are given names according to what goes on in them. Most rooms where people get paid to work in cubicles are called *offices*.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a room where people are primarily doing work at desks, then I would call that an *office*.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/office) gives this as one of the its three primary senses of *office*:

> : a building or room in which people work at desks doing business or professional activities

Comment: Right. It sounds like an *open-plan office* full of *cubicles* (or more pejoratively, a *cube farm* or *cubicle farm* full of *veal-fattening pens*). One who works in a cubicle is a *cubicle dweller*. http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/6/005/075/268/1d5fabd.jpg

Answer (score 3):

> Hall

In architecture, a hall is fundamentally a relatively large space enclosed by a roof and walls.

[wiki source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall)

Comment: This is not right. A hall needs only a roof. Walls are optional. "A hall is, fundamentally, a relatively large space enclosed by a roof such as a market hall."  -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_(concept)

Comment: Well, we've collectively provided 2 of 9 definitions from the OED.  I think the term still applies to the OP's question, walls or none.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments above, what's being described is an open-plan office. A somewhat informal single word for this type of workspace is [**bullpen**](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=bullpen+definition&oq=bullpen+definition&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l6.299.2361.0.2557.18.15.0.0.0.0.174.1372.0j11.11.0.hmcntrc%2Ccfro%3D1%2Chm-qwp-shp-ido%3D1%2Chm-qwp-shp-hmbtialc%3D1...0...1.1.64.hp..7.11.1370...5j0i131k1.TBtZ09ugyR4):

> an open-plan office area

Under "Other uses" of the Wikipedia entry<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullpen)</sup>, it states that "bullpen" is a "reference to a large open work area consisting of desks with no separating walls and private offices. Bullpens were common across many business fields in the first half of the 20th century and are often used by software development teams."

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I would be tempted to call it simply a 'space'.

[An interesting but typo-filled explanation of architectural space here](http://rinbo.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/form-space-order-summary.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A "great room" or a "great hall".